# How can user profile subtypes be assigned in batch?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, user-profile-service, audiences

Long story short, I don't want to have to go into each profile and assign them to a sub-type.  Can this be accomplished in batch somehow?

Ideally , it would be great to somehow use audiences.  If I have an audience setup for a subset of users and then somhow map the audiences to a different subtype.

If audiences cannot be used, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You must write a custom solution. Timerjob or something fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this out of the box. You would have to either use PowerShell or create a custom code solution.